# My computer freezes very often

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, freeze

My PC freezes once or twice a week leaving me no option but to restart. I have no idea what causes this.
I bought it 3 months ago and use it only for gaming and internet.

I scanned for viruses using Norton 360 and found nothing.

Specs:

```
Win7 ultimate
gigabyte p61 s3
8 GB ram corsair
galaxy GTX 560 SE Nvidia
1 TB seagate 5400 RPM
```

PS: Windows was not genuine when I bought the computer, but suddenly it became activated by itself.

Comment: It can be virus. If Norton couldn't catch, it doesn't mean there's no virus. Try smtg else like Kaspersky IS. Maybe someone is mining Bitcoin on your PC?...

Comment: i've tried Kaspersky and found no threats

Answer (score 2):

If the computer processor is getting too hot it can cause the computer to freeze.

You can first start by verifying the fan on the power supply is working by examining the back of the computer and seeing if the fan is moving and moving smoothly.

Comment: it's working fine and it sounds smooth

Comment: @Qadrology run some software like AIDA64 to see your fan speed. Maybe it's working in "half-speed"...

Comment: i'm using speedfan software and it says fans are good .. fan 1 1390 RPM fan2 950 RPM .. is that good ?

Answer (score 0):

Well if Windows was not genuine for some period of time that might explain why it is freezing. A not genuine Windows OS will not update and close security holes of the OS. You might have caught all kinds of Viruses and Malware which might have now root access and that is why your antivirus can not detect them. Also there is no way Windows 7 can get activated by itself. I suggest you delete your Windows OS and either buy Windows 7 or Windows 8 or if you want a free OS go with some Linux Distribution like Ubuntu.

---

The best tool to check what is wrong with your Windows OS is the [Windows Performance Analyser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh448170.aspx) which is a part of Windows Performance Toolkit. Also open your Resource Monitor [type in Search perfmon] and watch what's going on with your system. Also check your task manager to see what processes are running. And it the end you can try out the [Windows Assesment Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your Windows OS might be freezing for all kinds of reasons, like some program that is not well installed or some driver that is not updated, malware, viruses, and so on. Even your antivirus might be causing your system to freeze, uninstall it and try out [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download).

Comment: believe me the windows activated itself .. it's now downloading updates

Comment: @Qadrology but with every update Windows 7 might deactivate itself again if it detects that something was not right with the activation. Anyway did you try some suggestions from above ?

Comment: it have finished updating and it didn't deactivate .

Comment: yeah i've opened the dvd tray but nothing happened , installed kaspersky and malware software and found no threats , i also installed a fan software and it says fans are good .

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen with a wonky CD/DVD/Blu-Ray. To test this, leave the drive tray open for while using the system and see if it stops locking.

It's caused by the drive incorrectly reporting a new disk has been inserted, and the system pauses while it tries to refresh the drive's contents.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean but i left the tray opened for 5 mins and nothing happened, is that good ?

Comment: It depends on how often you were locking up. If it seems you don't lock up when you leave the tray open, it means you just need to replace that drive - fairly cheep fix... and you can just leave the tray open until you get around to it.
If the tray is open and it still locks, that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check all steps from scenario 3:

**Windows Kernel event ID 41 error "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first" in Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, or Windows Server 2008 R2**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Press the CAPS LOCK key on the keyboard. Does the light toggle? If yes, it is a software issue, if no, you have a hardware problem.

Comment: but how to know if my processor is overclocked or not ?

Comment: and my keyboadrd has no toggle lights

Comment: you no light on your keyboard to see the CAP LOCKS status? I've never seen this. To see if you overclocked, run CPU-Z

Comment: yeah there is no lights on the keyboard so what to do ?  i can't find this CPU-Z .

Comment: get CPU-Z from here: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your memory with [MemTest](http://www.memtest.org/), scan your HD with [SeaTools](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/)